# Achieving Time Complexity O(n) - Searching Preorder Binary Tree C++

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity, binary-tree

Binary Search Tree LCA
Have the function BinarySearchTreeLCA(strArr) take the array of strings stored in strArr, which will contain 3 elements: the first element will be a binary search tree with all unique values in a preorder traversal array, the second and third elements will be two different values, and your goal is to find the lowest common ancestor of these two values. For example: if strArr is ["[10, 5, 1, 7, 40, 50]", "1", "7"] then this tree looks like the following:

```
        10
       /  \
      5    40
     / \    \
    1   7    50
```

For the input above, your program should return 5 because that is the value of the node that is the LCA of the two nodes with values 1 and 7. You can assume the two nodes you are searching for in the tree will exist somewhere in the tree.

When submitting my code for this challenge the website calculates my time complexity to be O(n^2) when the most efficient is O(n).  I believe that the problem lies within the "build tree" function because the for loop calls a recursive "build tree".  Please help me identify what is causing my time complexity to be quadratic and the concept to achieve a linear time complexity

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;

    struct Node {
        int value;
        Node *parent = nullptr;
        Node *leftChild = nullptr;
        Node *rightChild = nullptr;
    };

    Node* findClosestParentOf(Node* n1, Node* n2) {
        vector<int> ancestVals;
        for (n1 = n1; n1 != nullptr; n1 = n1->parent) {
            ancestVals.push_back(n1->value);
        }

        for (n2 = n2; n2 != nullptr; n2 = n2->parent) {
            if (find(ancestVals.begin(), ancestVals.end(), n2->value) != ancestVals.end()) return n2;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    Node* searchNodeOf(Node* tree, int val) {
        if(tree->value == val) {
            return tree;
        }
        else {
            if (val < tree->value) return searchNodeOf(tree->leftChild, val);
            else return (searchNodeOf(tree->rightChild, val));
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    Node* createNode (Node *_parent, int _value) {
        Node *node = new Node;
        node->parent = _parent;
        node->value = _value;

        return node;
    }

    Node* buildTree(Node *&parent, int val) {
        if (val < parent->value) {
            if (parent->leftChild == nullptr) parent->leftChild = createNode(parent, val);
            else buildTree(parent->leftChild, val);
        }
        else {
            if (parent->rightChild == nullptr) parent->rightChild = createNode(parent, val);
            else buildTree(parent->rightChild, val);
        }

        return parent;
    }

    Node* buildTree(vector<int> values) {   
        Node *base = createNode(nullptr, values[0]); 

        for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++) {
            buildTree(base, values[i]);
        }
        return base;
    }

    vector<int> stringToInt(string str) {
        vector<int> vec;
        for (char* pch = strtok((char*)str.c_str(), "[ ,]"); pch != NULL; pch = strtok(NULL, "[ ,]")) {
            vec.push_back(stoi(pch));
        }

        return vec;
    }

    int BinarySearchTreeLCA(string strArr[], int length) { 
        vector<int> values = stringToInt(strArr[0]); //O(n)
        Node *tree = buildTree(values); //O(n^2)

        Node* n1 = searchNodeOf(tree, stoi(strArr[1])); //O(n)
        Node* n2 = searchNodeOf(tree, stoi(strArr[2])); //O(n)
        return findClosestParentOf(n1, n2)->value; //O(n)
    }

    int main(void) {
        string A[] = {"[3, 2, 1, 12, 4, 5, 13]", "5", "13"};
        int arrLength = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
        cout << BinarySearchTreeLCA(A, arrLength);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *"I believe that the problem lies within the 'build tree' function"* -- actually, the problem lies with the existence of a "build tree" function. Many challenge websites thrive by tricking gullible visitors into thinking the problem is one thing, when the problem is really another. The problems are not so much programming challenges as "can you find the hidden trick" challenges. If your solution seems straight-forward, you probably missed the trick that the site was going for.

Comment: *"Please help me identify what is causing my time complexity to be quadratic and the concept to achieve a linear time complexity"* -- this encompasses two questions. Are you more interested in analyzing your code, or are you more interested in the challenge website's trick? (If you want to ask about analyzing your code, your question might be better received if you provided some analysis on your part. Coming up with an analysis also might be good practice for you, possibly more beneficial than seeking the trick.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you have implemented is indeed not O(n). The `buildTree` function has in fact a O(nlogn) time complexity.

In order to solve this challenge with a linear time complexity, you could even omit building the binary search tree all together.

Instead, take these observations into consideration:

- If a node is a common ancestor then it must have a value that lies *between* the two target values.
- Not all values that are between the two target values are common ancestors.
- Not all common ancestors are values between the two target values
- There is actually only *one* value that lies between the two target values that is *also* a common ancestor. And this is the LCA.
- All other values that are between the two target values are necessarily part of the subtree rooted in that LCA node.
- As the nodes are given in preorder, the *first* value we find that lies between the two target values must be the LCA (for all of the above reasons)

The last point describes the linear algorithm you can implement, which is also a lot simpler than what you had done.

Comment: "This cannot be improved" Not a fact. Input is not arbitrary but given in a specific order, which can be used to improve the complexity.

Comment: Yes, @n.1.8e9, that's a correct remark.

Answer (score 0):

2nd iteration of code only searches through tree identifying common ancestors and returning the final ancestor.  Removing implementation of building binary tree and comparing 2 vectors (ancestral paths) improved the time complexity from O(n^2) to O(nlogn) according to website's time complexity calculator.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;


    int maxCalc(int a, int b) {return (a > b) ? a : b;}
    int minCalc(int a, int b) {return (a < b) ? a : b;}

    bool islastAncestor(int node, int max, int min) {return (min < node && max < node || min > node && max > node) ? false : true;}

    vector<int> stringToInt(string str) {
        vector<int> vec;
        for (char* pch = strtok((char*)str.c_str(), "[ ,]"); pch != NULL; pch = strtok(NULL, "[ ,]")) {
            vec.push_back(stoi(pch));
        }
        return vec;
    }

    int BinarySearchTreeLCA(string strArr[], int length) { 
        vector<int> tree = stringToInt(strArr[0]);
        int base = tree.front();
        int max = maxCalc(stoi(strArr[1]), stoi(strArr[2]));
        int min = minCalc(stoi(strArr[1]), stoi(strArr[2]));

        for(int i = 1; i < tree.size(); i++) {
            if (max > base && min > base) {
                if (tree[i] > base && islastAncestor(tree[i], max, min)) return tree[i];
            }
            else if (max < base && min < base && tree[i] < base) {
                if (tree[i] < base && islastAncestor(tree[i], max, min)) return tree[i];
            }
            else return base;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int main(void) {
        string A[] = {"[3, 2, 1, 12, 4, 5, 13]", "5", "4"};
        int arrLength = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
        cout << BinarySearchTreeLCA(A, arrLength);
        return 0;
    }
```